# How to send # character in URL

Tags: python, flask

I want to parse `GET` data which contains `#`(Example: `#HelloThere`). I'm getting below error

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/#Hello
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

### Code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<code>', methods=['GET'])
def convert(code):
    print code
    return json.dumps({"results": code}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How can I accept `GET` data which contains `#`?

I also tried `request.args.get('code')` and access `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/code=#FFFFFF`, still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting interpreted as a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

If you must pass a # character as data in the URL, try [urlencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the # character instead as %23

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/%23Hello
```

There's more complexity here which you can find in this SO answer:
[Python - Get URL fragment identifier with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566536/python-get-url-fragment-identifier-with-flask)